# Poisson process. Probability that next vehicle is a motorcycle.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

> On a particular highway cars pass as a possionprocess with intensity 3
>   cars per minute and motorcycles with intensity 1 motorcycles per
>   minute. Other types of vehicles are not counted.
>
> **a)** What is the probability that next vehicle that passes is a motorcycle?
>
> **b)** What is the probability that there will pass exactly $5$ vehicles during the next minute?
>
> **c)** What is the probability that there will pass exactly 3 cars before the next motorcycle?

I think I do understand what a possionprocess is. It's just impulses that happen (or points if you will) within an alotted period of time $t$ and the time inbetween these impulses $T_1,T_2...,T_n$ are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda t$.

**a):** Let $T_1$ be the time between cars and $T_2$ the time between motrocycles. So, mathematically we are looking for the probability that the time between cars is greater than time between motorcycles, that is $P(T_1>T_2)$. Computing this, in the book they say that

$$P(T_1>T_2)=\int_0^{\infty}(1-F_{T_1}(x))f_{T_2}(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-3x}e^{-x}=\frac{1}{4}.\tag1$$

Questions for **a)**:

1. I don't understand $(1)$. Why do I get that integral?
2. Is there another way to do this? Would it not, for example, be possiblt to compute $P(T_2<T_1)?$ How would this pan out?

---

For **b)** and **c)** I would just like some verification that everything is correct.

**b):** Let $X\sim \text{Poi}(3)$ be the number of cars that passes each minute, $Y\sim\text{Poi}(1)$ the number of motorcycles and $X+Y=Z\sim\text{Poi}(4)$ the number of vehicles. It can be proven by using PGF's that the sum of two random variables with Poisson distributions with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ have the convoluted distribution that is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda + \mu.$ So here we are looking for
$$P(Z=5)=\frac{e^{-4}\cdot 4^5}{5!}\approx 0.156.$$

**c)** Here we can use the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. In a we have that the probability that the next vehicle that passes is a car is $1-1/4=3/4$. So this has to happen 3 times first, and the 4'th vehicle has to be a motorcycle, that is

$$P=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=0.106.$$

Comment: Your problem says motorcycles come by 3 per minute, but your calculations hint that it is 1 per minute. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. It's 1/minute.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see that the integral in (a) is correct is to look at a discrete example. Let's assume that $T_2$ takes on discrete values $1,2,\dots$ and so on. Then, by conditioning on $T_2$ and using the law of total probability,
$$ P(T_1 > T_2) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(T_1 > T_2 | T_2 = x) P(T_2 = x) \\
= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(T_1 > x | T_2 = x) P(T_2 = x) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(T_1 > x) P(T_2 = x). $$
The continuous analog would be an integral instead of a sum and $P(T_2=x)$ should be replaced by its density. I hope this makes the argument clearer to you!

Yes, you could do it differently by calculating $P(T_1<T_2)$ in a similar fashion. However, this doesn't make the argument easier in any sense.

b) and c) look fine to me.

**Edit**: I cannot find a proof of the exact verification of just replacing the summation by the integral as I suggested. I am not sure but it might be an application of the Law of total expectation. Some would call this actually the continuous analog of the total law of probability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't really understand how LoTP can be used in that sense. What exactly is your first equationline saying? Why do we have to multply the summand with $P(T_2=x)$?

Comment: The first equation is actually applying the law of total probability: $P(A) = \sum_x P(A|B_x)P(B_x)$ where in this case (so the simplified discrete case), $A=(T_1>T_2)$, the event that $T_1$ exceeds $T_2$, and $B_x = (T_2 = x)$, the event that $T_2$ equals $x$.

Comment: On the second line, you basically state that $$P(T_1>x|T_2=x)P(T_2=x)=P(T_1>x)P(T_2=x).$$ Let $A:=T_1>x$ and $B:=T_2=x,$ This means that $$P(A|B)=P(A)Å(B),$$ which is only true if $A$ and $B$ are independent events. This does not make sense becuse why would we condition if they are independent?

Comment: Well, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent. Thus $A$ and $B$ are infact independent. We do need to use the law of total probability to simplify the problem. However, you could also use the version $P(A) = \sum_x P(A\text{\ and\ }B_x)$ which simplifies similarly. However, I do think that my calculation is more intuitive.

Comment: Do you understand it now or do you have more questions? (Btw in my last comment the '\' is a typo.)